# Sort a map by nested map value in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have this map:

```
def mapToSort = [one:[count:10], two:[count:20], three:[count:30]]
```

And want to sort it descending by the sub-map attribute "count" so the result should be:

```
[three:[count:30], two:[count:20], one:[count:10]]
```

I tried this without success:

```
mapToSort.sort{ a, b -> b.value.count <=> a.value.count }
mapToSort.sort{ -it.value.count }
```

Comment: I think what you tried `mapToSort.sort{ a, b -> b.value.count <=> a.value.count }` is correct. Can you tell us what is the output of this operation? It gives correct result when I have tried it groovy console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your sorting is ok but the result is a new sorted map. Try this:

```
def sortedMap = mapToSort.sort{ a, b -> b.value.count <=> a.value.count }
println sortedMap
```